# How to decrypt a 'clear text YAML file' with vaulted variable?

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I'm using ansible 2.7.16.

The ansible documentation says:

```
Single Encrypted Variable

As of version 2.3, Ansible can now use a vaulted variable that lives in an otherwise ‘clear text’ YAML file:

notsecret: myvalue
mysecret: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          66386439653236336462626566653063336164663966303231363934653561363964363833313662
          6431626536303530376336343832656537303632313433360a626438346336353331386135323734
          62656361653630373231613662633962316233633936396165386439616533353965373339616234
          3430613539666330390a313736323265656432366236633330313963326365653937323833366536
          34623731376664623134383463316265643436343438623266623965636363326136
other_plain_text: othervalue
```

I have the following .yml file:

```
user: dbuser
pass: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          33633131346338633461336438656463643539396535656432306564636466353338373135346166
          3838313236383739616239333265323131376231656633350a613333613239646263393330353930
          31303935646330643831396130343031613063393839353433646338343034386432656435623934
          6537356530643136310a373835323666393337346562613831613962323261346232323331343631
          3838
```

I would like get a decrypted file, then I tried the command:

`ansible-playbook --vault-password-file pass.txt config.yml`

But I got the following error:

```
 [WARNING]: Unable to parse /etc/ansible/hosts as an inventory source

 [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

ERROR! playbooks must be a list of plays

The error appears to have been in '/tmp/config.yml': line 1, column 1, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


user: dbuser
^ here
```

How could I get the .yml file with the variables decrypted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"How could I get the .yml file decrypted ?"*

A: Simply use the file as any other file with variables. For example

```
shell> ansible-vault encrypt_string 'password' --name 'pass'
pass: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          65303631663061316538623639316439366538386430656239383735353237343762346364653230
          3163643637333966643762383733633465353065333564310a303762343732613363313864646661
          66633539363865386362613362663238353664356439386431303065646530666562326662356439
          3032313564373364360a623830613763616635383633363631356535316162393138373336386534
          3835
```

```
shell> cat conf1.yml 
pass: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          65303631663061316538623639316439366538386430656239383735353237343762346364653230
          3163643637333966643762383733633465353065333564310a303762343732613363313864646661
          66633539363865386362613362663238353664356439386431303065646530666562326662356439
          3032313564373364360a623830613763616635383633363631356535316162393138373336386534
          3835
```

```
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_vars: conf1.yml
    - debug:
        var: pass
```

gives

```
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml
...
    "pass": "password"
```

---

A: Optionally *`decrypt`* the file the same way it was *`encrypt`ed*. For example

```
shell> cat conf.yml 
user: dbuser

shell> ansible-vault encrypt conf.yml 
Encryption successful

shell> cat conf.yml 
$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
63313762343630623364653737643462373034653762616333663330613039623534633030666135
6633343263666465356537316430623834386130626231310a376639356234336664386239336461
31313935613565656639653532613639396536326662346234373563663065643564373939316539
3430643635623339390a393139326337306363623565356439626430643161356266323832313461
3633

shell> ansible-vault decrypt conf.yml 
Decryption successful

shell> cat conf.yml 
user: dbuser
```

---

A: In a playbook, simply use it as any other file with variables. For example the playbook

```
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_vars: conf.yml
    - debug:
        var: user
```

gives

```
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml
...
    "user": "dbuser"
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir. I'm not encrypting the whole file. I'm encrypting only variables values `ansible-vault encrypt_string 'string' --name 'variable_name`

Comment: Then, why are you asking "how to decrypt the file"?

Comment: I thought the message it was clear. I'm showing a .yml file with some variables encrypted.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how to do all vaulted values, but [`yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) and piping  works for decrypting single ones:

```
yq e ".pass" config.yml | ansible-vault decrypt
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is a other way that putting the encrypted variable into a separate file, indent it and use:

```
ansible-vault decrypt var_in_file.yml
```

Also, answer with using yq for single vars might work too:

```
yq -r ".variable" ansible_playbook.yml > var_in_file.txt
ansible-vault decrypt var_in_file.yml
```

But on the second case, I'm not sure if the indentation is kept.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43467180/how-to-decrypt-string-with-ansible-vault-2-3-0)